# Regex to search all directories whose name contains one of the two substrings

Tags: regex, bash

I'm a actually working on a **Bash Script** that search the backups directories to delete.

I have a directory `~/test/` that contain some "backups" directories named as follow :

```
20200302_000001-daily
20200330_000001-monthly
20200528_000001-weekly
20200529_000001-daily
20200530_000001-daily
20200531_000001-monthly
20200601_000001-daily
20200602_000001-daily
```

With a `find` command, I'm trying to **record all directory's name that contain the string `daily` or `weekly`** in an array :

`` BACKUPS=(`find $BACKUP_DIR -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*[daily|weekly]$"`) `` // where `$BACKUP_DIR` is the absolute path to the "test" directory.

The problem is, that the regex match all the backups directories and after hours of research, I didn't find why.

It's interesting to know that if I use the regex `.*daily$`, the regex match all the "daily" backups directories (and `.*weekly$` match all the "weekly" backups directories).

I know there are other ways to do it, but I really want to success with a regex.

Comment: Try ``BACKUPS=(`find $BACKUP_DIR -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*/.*\(daily\|weekly\)$"`)``

Comment: @HezelTm : What do you mean by a "string being in an array"? In this context, this does not make sense. BTW, you don't need regular expressions for this. You can alternatively ask for `-name "*daily" -o "*weekly"`, if you prefer.

Comment: @user1934428 : I don't understand, I don't see in my post something about "string being in an array" (maybe someone edited the post and I just don't remember). And yes I know I can do that without a regex ; as I said in the post  : "I really want to succes with a regex". :)

Comment: To quote your questions: *I'm trying to record all directory's name that contain the string daily or weekly in an array*. If someone else edited this, please edit it back to something sensible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a regex that will match the whole input and contains a grouping construct rather than a bracket expression:

```
BACKUPS=(`find $BACKUP_DIR -maxdepth 1 -regex ".*/.*\(daily\|weekly\)$"`)
```

Here, the POSIX BRE pattern means:

- `.*/` - match any 0 or more chars up to the last `/`
- `.*` - any 0 or more chars up to
- `\(daily\|weekly\)` - either  `daily` or `weekly` *character sequences* (note that `[day|week]` is the same as `[adekwy|]` since it is a bracket expression)
- `$` - end of string.